# Prototype and TypeError: someFunction is not a constructor

Tags: javascript

I have got a question about the behaviour of Javascript with respect to prototypes, variables declarations and constructors.

Why this works:

```
var myFunction = function(){ alert('something')};
myFunction.prototype = (function() { 
                                     var a='something else'; 
                                     return {method:a} 
                                   } () );
var obj = new myFunction();
console.log(obj.method); // the message 'something else' is logged
```

whereas this does not work:

```
var myFunction = (function() { 
                              var a='something else'; 
                              return {method:a} 
                              } () );
var obj = new myFunction();
console.log(obj.method);
```

it throws:

```
Uncaught TypeError: myFunction is not a constructor(…)
```

**ANSWER**: the below answer revealed that in the second case we are not initializing `var myFunction` with the `function` keyword; rather we are only returning a JSON object with a property named `method` which results into an error when executing `var obj = new myFunction();`.

Comment: Right, `myFunction` is not a function and therefore not a constructor. You've invoked the function and returned an object, so you're basically doing `var myFunction = {method: "something else"}; new myFunction()`. So this isn't related to hoisting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this has nothing to do with hoisting. If we strip away the IIFE and the local variable, your first snippet becomes

```
var myFunction = function() {
    alert('something');
};
myFunction.prototype = {
    method: 'something else'
};
var obj = new myFunction();
console.log(obj.method);
```

whereas the second one becomes

```
var myFunction = {
    method: 'something else'
};
var obj = new myFunction();
console.log(obj.method);
```

which quite obviously cannot work.

Maybe you intended to write

```
var obj = (function() { 
    var a = 'something else'; 
    return {method:a} 
}());
console.log(obj.method); // the message 'something else' is logged
```

Comment: ok, so in the second case, myFunction is not a function, so no constructor can be called. The immediately-invoked function expression confused me.

Comment: @Johan Yes, exactly.